# Dynamically change colors in linegraph before and after event

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics

Suppose I have a linegraph with n lines.
Each line has a corresponding x-axis value for which I want a different color before and after a specific event.

For example, each person starts as the color green, but when they have an event, the line color switches to red.

I was able to find a solution in base using loops, looking for a base or ggplot solution.

[image: Example of desired response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lines <- data.frame(id = rep(c("A","B"), each = 5),
                    x = 1:5,
                    val = 1:10)

events <-data.frame(id = c("A","B"),
                    time = c(3, 4))

library(tidyverse)
lines %>%
  left_join(events) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(status = if_else(x < time, "before", "after")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, val, color = status, group = id)) +
  geom_line(size = 4)
```

[image]